# Action Script 3 keyboard event set focus

Tags: actionscript-3

I set focus to a text field in the init method, however keyboard enter event only works when I click the text field first.

What is the problem?

Comment: Embedding issue The swf doesn't have focus at all.

Comment: Duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096909/flash-as3-keyboardevent-not-firing/12097074#12097074

Comment: How are you setting the focus?

Answer (score 0):

It's because, in AS3, by default, `stage` got the focus. So if you are adding a keyboard event listener to anything other than `stage` you have to set focus to that object. 
Example,
If `txt` is your text field, you are adding a keyboard event listener to `txt` then you must do get focus for that like

```
stage.focus = txt;
```

That line brought focus to the text field but remember if you click on anything other than that, that object got focus. Needless to say, `txt` lost focus.

**Tip**: Try using adding keyboard event listener to `stage`, if you do so then it dispatches the event when a key is clicked or released regardless of the what object has focus.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyBoardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
```